# How to make Embest Board interactive in ARMSim

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm working with ARMSim and have to use the Embest Board plug-in. The program requires us to use the buttons on the board while the program is running, however I'm not sure how to make the program interactive. It simply runs the code I have and then exits. What piece of code do I need to make sure the program keeps running and allows for the user to click on the various buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a look through the docs (I've not actually used it), the only interface to the buttons is a couple of SWI calls (0x202 and 0x203) that will tell you which, if any, buttons have been pressed. Therefore it appears your only option is to use a polling loop to repeatedly check the relevant button state, and branch off to different subroutines to do something interesting when a given button's bit is set to indicate it was clicked.

It looks like there's already a pretty complete example at the end of the manual (11.6), so here's a relevant excerpt from that:

```
    ...
LB1:
    swi      SWI_CheckBlack            @get button press into R0
    cmp      r0,#0
    beq      LB1                       @ if zero, no button pressed
    ...
    @ goes on to work out which button was pressed and do stuff accordingly
```